# Scheduled task starts one hour earlier than scheduled - Windows 7

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I had scheduled a task to begin at a particular time each night ( on my old laptop).  I had to start using it again and I noticed that it started it one hour earlier than scheduled. I changed the time to an hour later than I really want it to start, but that seems really strange that I should have to do that. I have Windows 7.

Comment: Affected by DST somehow?

Comment: Is the system clock correct?  Are you now located in a different time zone than the last time you used it?